# Editing Totals block on Magento Order Emails

Tags: magento, email, styling, mage

I'm working with my magento order emails and the subtotal and grand total lines are flushed to the right rather than staying contained within the specs of the email template.

Does anyone know where I can style this block so it fits correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales` for email templates..